# Property binding map click event with dropdown select input in ngx-leaflet/Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, property-binding, ngx-leaflet

I have a map with regional polygons. Below the map, I have a dropdown select input that dynamically reads in the polygon names as options. When the user clicks the regional polygons on the map, I want the dropdown select input to update with the selected polygon name (which exists as the 'name' field in the geojson file).

I figure that the way to achieve this is to use property binding in the HTML template file. So in my select class, I set the value property as the value `clicked`, like so:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectRegion" [value]="clicked">
```

`clicked` is initially defined as an empty string in the app component. When a polygon is clicked, I set `clicked` as the polygon name field inside the `onEachFeature` click event. The console log shows that the `clicked` variable is updating properly. However, the select input does NOT update with the click events as expected.

I suspect that the issue is that `this` isn't properly updating inside my functions? How do I get the select input to update with my map click events?

Here's some code (based on ngx-leaflet-tutorial-ngcli from Asymmetrik):

Geojson (saved as `polygons.geojson` in the assets folder:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "#555555",
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "fill": "#555555",
        "fill-opacity": 0.5,
        "name": "poly1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -121.95098876953125,
              46.82966386051541
            ],
            [
              -121.78482055664061,
              46.82966386051541
            ],
            [
              -121.78482055664061,
              46.91368905872705
            ],
            [
              -121.95098876953125,
              46.91368905872705
            ],
            [
              -121.95098876953125,
              46.82966386051541
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "#555555",
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "fill": "#555555",
        "fill-opacity": 0.5,
        "name": "poly2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -121.77726745605469,
              46.83107318799318
            ],
            [
              -121.62963867187499,
              46.83107318799318
            ],
            [
              -121.62963867187499,
              46.913220009605624
            ],
            [
              -121.77726745605469,
              46.913220009605624
            ],
            [
              -121.77726745605469,
              46.83107318799318
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

App.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LeafletModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

App.component.html:

```
<div class="map"
  leaflet
  [leafletLayers]="layers"
     [leafletFitBounds]="fitBounds"></div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="selectRegion" [value] = "clicked">
    <option *ngFor="let region of regions">{{ region }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

App.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  layers: L.Layer[];
  fitBounds = [[46.67, -122.25], [47.01, -121.302]];
  regions = [];
  clicked = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    // read in geojson of poly
    this.http.get<any>('/assets/polygons.geojson')
      .subscribe(poly => {

        const tileLayer = L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          subdomains: 'abcd',
          maxZoom: 19
        });

        const polyLayer = L.geoJSON(poly, {
          onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature.bind(this)
        });

        this.layers = [ tileLayer, polyLayer ];
        console.log(this);
      });
  }

  // loop through each feature of polyLayer
  onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

    // push polygon names to regions array
    this.regions.push(feature.properties.name);

    layer.on('click', <LeafletMouseEvent> (e) => {
      this.clicked = e.target.feature.properties.name;
      console.log(this.clicked);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onEachFeature` function and `layer.on('click'...` event callback are likely being invoked outside of the Angular zone. If this is the case, then change detection won't automatically work. You should wrap the changes in `zone.run()` calls in order to ensure that your changes are being made in the Angular zone - as in this example:

```
// loop through each feature of polyLayer
onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

  this.zone.run(() => {
    // push polygon names to regions array
    this.regions.push(feature.properties.name);

    layer.on('click', <LeafletMouseEvent> (e) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.clicked = e.target.feature.properties.name;
        console.log(this.clicked);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

You can follow these directions (https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet#a-note-about-change-detection) to see how this works and to inject the ngZone instance into your component.