# Updating ngx-leaflet map based on Bootstrap select input

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, leaflet, bootstrap-select, ngx-leaflet

I have an app that updates a Bootstrap select input dropdown menu when you click a polygon on the map in ngx-leaflet based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702519/property-binding-map-click-event-with-dropdown-select-input-in-ngx-leaflet-angul). I want to be able to also select a polygon name from the select input and have the same functionality as the click event--in this case, using `fitBounds` to pan and zoom to the selected polygon.

I added event binding to my HTML template, which detects each new selection from the dropdown menu. I passed a new function, `onChange()` to that event. But I'm stumped where to go from here. In the click event, I am able to use `e.target` to access the bounds of the selected polygon. But inside `onChange()`, all I have access to is the name of the selected polygon, but I don't actually have the geometry associated with that polygon. So how am I able to use the dropdown select input to select a polygon name and have the map update the polygon associated with that name? (Please note that I am hoping for a flexible response, as I would like to do more than just `fitBounds()` in my actual app outside of this example.)

Here is my example code:

**polygons.geojson** (in `assets` folder)

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "#555555",
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "fill": "#555555",
        "fill-opacity": 0.5,
        "name": "poly1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -121.95098876953125,
              46.82966386051541
            ],
            [
              -121.78482055664061,
              46.82966386051541
            ],
            [
              -121.78482055664061,
              46.91368905872705
            ],
            [
              -121.95098876953125,
              46.91368905872705
            ],
            [
              -121.95098876953125,
              46.82966386051541
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "#555555",
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "fill": "#555555",
        "fill-opacity": 0.5,
        "name": "poly2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -121.77726745605469,
              46.83107318799318
            ],
            [
              -121.62963867187499,
              46.83107318799318
            ],
            [
              -121.62963867187499,
              46.913220009605624
            ],
            [
              -121.77726745605469,
              46.913220009605624
            ],
            [
              -121.77726745605469,
              46.83107318799318
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="map"
  leaflet
  [leafletLayers]="layers"
     [leafletFitBounds]="fitBounds"></div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select [(ngModel)]="selected" class="form-control" id="selectRegion" [value]="clicked" (change)="onChange()">
    <option *ngFor="let region of regions">{{ region }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, NgZone, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  layers: L.Layer[];
  fitBounds = [[46.67, -122.25], [47.01, -121.302]];
  regions = [];
  clicked = '';
  selected = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    // read in geojson of poly
    this.http.get<any>('/assets/polygons.geojson')
      .subscribe(poly => {

        const tileLayer = L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          subdomains: 'abcd',
          maxZoom: 19
        });

        const polyLayer = L.geoJSON(poly, {
          onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature.bind(this)
        });

        this.layers = [ tileLayer, polyLayer ];
      });
  }

  // loop through each feature of polyLayer
  onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      // push polygon names to regions array
      this.regions.push(feature.properties.name);

      layer.on('click', <LeafletMouseEvent> (e) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.fitBounds = e.target.getBounds();
          this.clicked = e.target.feature.properties.name;
        });
      });
    });
  }

  onChange() {
    console.log(this.selected);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by first initializing `polyLayer` as a null attribute at the top of my App Component class before `constructor()`. So I updated instances of `polyLayer` to `this.polyLayer` throughout the rest of the code. With this, I am now able to access the polygons inside `onChange()`, filter with `eachLayer()`, and fit the bounds of the map:

**app.component.ts update**

```
import {Component, NgZone, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  layers: L.Layer[];
  fitBounds = [[46.67, -122.25], [47.01, -121.302]];
  regions = [];
  clicked = '';
  selected = '';
  polyLayer = null;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    // read in geojson of poly
    this.http.get<any>('/assets/polygons.geojson')
      .subscribe(poly => {

        const tileLayer = L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          subdomains: 'abcd',
          maxZoom: 19
        });

        this.polyLayer = L.geoJSON(poly, {
          onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature.bind(this)
        });

        this.layers = [ tileLayer, this.polyLayer ];
      });
  }

  // loop through each feature of polyLayer
  onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      // push polygon names to regions array
      this.regions.push(feature.properties.name);

      layer.on('click', <LeafletMouseEvent> (e) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.fitBounds = e.target.getBounds();
          this.clicked = e.target.feature.properties.name;
        });
      });
    });
  }

  onChange() {

    let that = this;

    // console.log(this.polyLayer._layers);
    this.polyLayer.eachLayer(function(layer){
      if(layer.feature.properties.name === that.selected){
        that.fitBounds = layer.getBounds();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the object for the select input, you should use `[ngValue]` to explicitly set the value object:

```
<div class="map"
     leaflet
     [leafletLayers]="layers"
     [leafletFitBounds]="fitBounds"></div>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="selectRegion"
          (change)="onChange()"
          [(ngModel)]="selected" >
    <option *ngFor="let region of regions"
            [ngValue]="region">{{ region }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

But, you still have the issue that now you have to set `selected` to the region object when you click on the map. So, you might need to change how your map click code works to ensure you can get a reference to the right object when you click the map.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this binding is different. Do you have any insight on how to access the map/polygons inside `onChange()` to perform the same as a leaflet event? I tried adding the geojson call inside `onChange`, but I still don't have a way to update the map based on the select input rather than a leaflet event like a click or mouesover in `onEachFeature`. Basically, I need a way to associate the string 'poly1/2' from the select input to the actual geojson named the same way.

Comment: The idea with this code snippet is that the value that gets bound to `ngModel` is going to be whatever you bind to `ngValue` when that option is selected. So, in this example, regions could be a collection of objects that each contain a label and a reference to a polygon. And you'd only have to update the display value for each object to be the label, while the `ngValue` is the object so you can access the polygon directly.